# Assigning a public ip address to an existing nic in Azure using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, networking, command-line-interface, nic

Using Azure CLI, it's possible to create and assign a public ip address to an existing nic e.g.

**Create a public ip in a given resource group and region**

```
azure network public-ip create -g myresourcegroup -a Dynamic -l westus mypublicipname
```

**Assign the pip created in previous step to an existing nic**

```
azure network nic set -g myresourcegroup -p mypublicipname mynicname
```

However similar code in powershell doesn't work e.g.

**Create a new pip (completes successfully)**

```
$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $pipName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locName -AllocationMethod Dynamic -Force
```

**Assign to an existing nic**

```
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $nicName
```

> ```
> $nic.IpConfigurations[0].PublicIpAddress = $pip.IpAddress
> ```

**Last line doesn't work and throws the following error:**

```
The property 'Id' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:31 char:9
+         $nic.IpConfigurations[0].PublicIpAddress.Id = $pip.Id
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Though intellisense in PS ISE does show Id property for both! Does anyone knows if this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Tim Wieman (MSFT) of AzureCAT for the solution! Basically you need to assign the newly created pip to nic's PublicIPAddress property and then run Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface command as below:

```
    $nic.IpConfigurations[0].PublicIpAddress = $pip 
    Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
```